# How to convert Image to multipart file in spring

Tags: java, spring, image

I have an image file and creating `File` object with that image

`File file = new File("E://Shared Data/Images/xyz.jpg");`

The above line is creating a `file` object with some size like `440272`, I need to convert the above `image file` into `multipart file` for that I did

```
DiskFileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "image/png", false, file.getName(),
                                    (int) file.length(), file.getParentFile());
                            fileItem.getOutputStream();
                            MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
                            adminAssetUploadController.upload(request, multipartFile, "product", null);
```

the problem is after converting I am getting `size=0` instead of getting some `size`  like `440272`. If I get `size` for the `image` so that I can store into some some location by passing it to `upload` method.

below is the upload method

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> upload(HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable(value = "sectionKey") String sectionKey,
            @PathVariable(value = "id") String id) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        properties.put("entityType", sectionKey);
        properties.put("entityId", id);

        StaticAsset staticAsset = staticAssetService.createStaticAssetFromFile(file, properties);
        staticAssetStorageService.createStaticAssetStorageFromFile(file, staticAsset);
         ........
         .......

}
```

can anyone help me why I am getting `zero size` after converting into `multipart file` is my approach is correct to convert `image file` to `multipart file`? or I need to follow any other `approach` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest convert the image by using this code

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileItem);
MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("fileItem",
            fileItem.getName(), "image/png", IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
```

If you would like to use CommonsMultipartFile, I think you should have into your pom file the commons-fileupload

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.3</version> 
</dependency>
```

The documentation of CommonsMultipartFile states that

> NOTE: As of Spring 2.0, this class requires Commons FileUpload 1.1 or
>   higher. The implementation does not use any deprecated FileUpload 1.0
>   API anymore, to be compatible with future Commons FileUpload releases.
>   http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: `MockMultipartFile` yeah it worked thank you very much.