# Process MultipartFile in serverless application on java11 without spring

Tags: java, multipartform-data, java-11, multipartfile

I need to develop the severless application using java11 without spring. In this application i need to open an endpoint where the consumer is multipart/form-data. I know in spring we have a MultipartFile class using which we can grab the object and use it but i want to know how to do it without spring. After that i need to upload that file in amazon S3. 
I am using Amazon Api gateway to expose the endpoint and amazon s3 for storage.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956365/spring-rest-multipart-file-upload-with-java-configuration-without-spring-boot) help?

Comment: No, its using spring but we don't want to use any framework.

Comment: Could you improve your question? The "using java11 **with** spring" is sorta misleading, given that a sentence later you're saying "without spring".

Comment: Thank you, just edited. I want the ans wothout spring.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So you want to create a Java-App, which **accepts** `multipart/form-data`? Are you using jakarta/javax by any chance?

Comment: javax yes we are using

Comment: not the upload part just how to grab the multipart file from the restapi

Comment: Are you developing an application with servlets?

Comment: application is serverless. using aws lambda

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://github.com/CorkHounds/multipart-fileupload-java-lambda/blob/master/src/main/java/fileupload/FileUploadFunctionHandler.java) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875504/parse-multipart-form-data-body-on-aws-lambda-in-java).

Comment: @Shivam so you ARE using libraries, you said you don't want to...

Comment: Are you allowed to use jax-rs and jersey (glassfish) libraries?

Comment: Can use library but not from spring.

Comment: You need to include some code in this. "i need to open an endpoint where the consumer is multipart/form-data." What is this? How are you obtaining it? Do you have an actual java class that this is in reference to? Are you trying to handle an http request that has multipart/form-data?

Comment: The JavaMail library, part of standard Java EE, includes a [MimeMultipart](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html) class.

Comment: Can you possibly add serverless to the title somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that on the way to your Serverless Java Lambda the AWS ApiGateway will transform your request into JSON for passing through to Lambda.

To get this to work for multipart form you need to [define multipart/form-data as a binary media type for your API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html) and proxy the payload directly to a Lambda function.

This is how you [implement the Lambda in Java](https://medium.com/swlh/processing-multipart-form-data-using-api-gateway-and-a-java-lambda-proxy-for-storage-in-s3-e6598033ff3e) to consume the resulting payload.

No Spring in sight. Just apache commons and aws stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked for me. It take some time to figure out how to do it in my code.

Comment: My pleasure. Can you please put “serverless” in the question title somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want to use ANY libraries?
In that case you first have to implement your own code to handle http requests, and then code to extract the data you want from them.

I seriously doubt you want to do that (though it's an interesting exercise if you have the time and skill).

But if you insist, the HTTP RFC is where you want to start.